# text only from title to make seo url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am working on code where i upload html code and same code is added as content with top char being title and seo url.

but i had issue with making title as unable to get only plain text from html string to use it as title and seo url

below is my code to get title from html text:

```
$title = getplaintextintrofromhtml($str,100);
$title = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $title);
$title = str_replace("  "," ", $title);

$title = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|,+=-'), '', $title);
$title = str_replace("'","", $title);
$title = str_replace("<br>","", $title);
$title = str_replace("\n","", $title);
$title = trim($title);
```

**seo url** 
    $newurltitle=str_replace(" ","-",$title);

and function

```
function getplaintextintrofromhtml($html, $numchars) {
    // Remove the HTML tags
    $html = strip_tags($html);
    // Convert HTML entities to single characters
    $html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    // Make the string the desired number of characters
    // Note that substr is not good as it counts by bytes and not characters
    $html = mb_substr($html, 0, $numchars, 'UTF-8');
    // Add an elipsis
    return $html;
}
```

even after my above code i get titles with new line , i could not figure out why this happens even thought i am getting plain text but issue like new line still there and i can not use them to make seo url also

Comment: new line can be two symbols `\r` and `\n`, you're replacing only `\n`

Comment: For $title str_replace you can pass all search values in array and then replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to remove newlines, extra spaces, and line feeds:

```
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title);
```

Comment: $title =  preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title); like that

Comment: @saurav, that is correct. Could you test it and check if this gives you the correct result?